# Using native resolution on external display results in stretched, out of bounds image

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, netbook, nvidia-ion

I have an HP min 311 netbook with Windows XP, which I've connected to a Samsung SyncMaster 2043BW display via the supplied analog cable.

The external display's native res is 1680x1050, which the netbook's ION GPU supports.
I've configured the external display as the single display (no cloning or any such fancy stuff).

However, once I set the native res, the image just stretches out. It looks squashed, and it goes outside the monitor's edges. In contrast, lower resolutions manage to stay within the monitor's display edges, though obviously they are skewed in some way (vertically or horizontally).

BTW, the only res which seems to be displayed relatively clearly (it's the least blurry) is 1280x720.

I tried looking all over the web for an explanation/advice but could not find any.

I already played with the settings on the external display itself several times. So either it's not that, or I missed something.

Has someone run into this issue? I need help.

Comment: How is the netbook connected to the monitor? Which connection type (cable) do you use?

Comment: The netbook is connected via the monitor's supplied analog cable

Answer (score 1):

Check the monitor settings (the *real* monitor settings, which to set on the monitor directly). Maybe the aspect ratio is wrong or any other setting if out of bound.

Comment: already done that, several times :)

Answer (score 1):

As the monitor is connected with the analog VGA-cable, I assume that the monitor is using overscan mode. Thus, you might be able to correct the image by using the monitor's geometric settings like width and height.

Additionally, VGA is not designed for such high resolutions as you are using. Maybe this can cause the problem. Does it work better with lower resolutions?

Comment: I find this a little hard to accept as all the resolutions up to the native one are handled by the monitor just fine (albeit squished a little). It's just that native one that freaks out.

Comment: also, as for the overscan thing - why does only the native one needs it and not other res? (ress? reses?)

Comment: Maybe because VGA can't handle this high resolution optimally.